# YouCompleteMe and Pyenv virtualenvs

Tags: python, vim

I create a virtualenv using pyenv and then activate it in a directory using `pyenv local`:

```
 pyenv virtaulenv 3.4.2 3.4.2-my_project
 pyenv local 3.4.2-my_project
```

After that I install libraries using `pip` as usual.
The problem is that when I open VIM with `YouCompleteMe` installed it does not find definitions as type for python packages I've installed in a virtualenv. It loads information about the packages from system-wide places.

Should I install and use `pyenv` plugin for VIM or should I tweak my `vimrc` somehow?

#### Edit

Posted an [issue](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1388) on GitHub.

Comment: According to this issue (https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/380) it's most likely a problem caused by Jedi, you could try that :)

Comment: @Wolph unfortunetly thiis is not about my problem. Suggested `vim-virtual` module does not work with pyenv as it invokes `activate.py`. Suggested `vim` hook also is all about triggering `activate.py`. Also they mention that everything works if VIM is launched from a virtualenv dir which is wrong in my case. It does not.

Comment: I'm guessing it's still not related to YCM but to jedi instead, using python 3 could be part of the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I got this running on `elementary os 0.4.1 Loki` (fairly assuming all Debian based systems should work).

It's practically impossible to get `YouCompleteMe` working if you install it using `vundle` or any other plugin manager for `vim`. So the best option is to follow the installation instructions on [github](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/).

Once installed I put this piece of code in `.vimrc`:

```
if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
  project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
  activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir, 'bin/activate_this.py')
  execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

after few moments of indexing `YouCompleteMe` started detecting package information from the virtual environment.

Comment: btw you're missing `endif` at the end of that code block

Comment: @RichardG This is Python code, so there is no `endif` keyword. At first I thought you were right, so I just edited it, but fortunately one of the reviewers was keen enough to notice: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20220216.

Comment: It matches a snippet here: https://realpython.com/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/ which uses a .vimrc feature I cannot see documented, to run Python2 code within .vimr. I've put in an edit to add the necessary `py << EOF` markup. `py3` will run Python3 instead, and you need to replace `execfile(` with `eval(open(`. However my Python completer is still using Python2 with that change so I didn't include it in my edit.

Comment: @JackDeeth - Can you explain how you got this to work? I don't have an `activate_this.py` in my virtual environment.